# Why the database doesn't see the table?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am fresh to flask and I would be really grateful if someone can help me because I can't deal with this problem all day.
I have defined the table named "users" then run `main.py` and it's all OK. But when I try to update the table, error 
`"sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: users" occures.`
Please help, I feel really helpless.

Here's my code:

project\main.py

```
from flask import Flask
from data import db_session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret_key'

db_session.global_init("db/blogs.sqlite")


def main():
    app.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

project\data\db_session.py

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative as dec


SqlAlchemyBase = dec.declarative_base()

__factory = None


def global_init(db_file):
    global __factory

    if __factory:
        return

    if not db_file or not db_file.strip():
         raise Exception("You must specify a database file.")

    conn_str = f'sqlite:///{db_file.strip() check_same_thread=False'
    print(f"Connect to the database at {conn_str}")

    engine = sa.create_engine(conn_str, echo=False)
    __factory = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    from data import __all_models

    SqlAlchemyBase.metadata.create_all(engine)


def create_session() -> Session:
    global __factory
    return __factory()
```

project\data__all_models.py

```
from data import users
```

project\data\users.py

```
import datetime
import sqlalchemy
from data.db_session import SqlAlchemyBase 
from data import db_session


class User(SqlAlchemyBase):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer,
                       primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, nullable=True)
    about = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, nullable=True)
    email = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String,
                          index=True, unique=True, nullable=True)
    hashed_password = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, nullable=True)
    created_date = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.DateTime,
                                 default=datetime.datetime.now)




user = User()
user.name = "user 1"
user.about = "user's bio"
user.email = "email@email"
session = db_session.create_session()
session.add(user)
session.commit()
```

Comment: You need to let SQLAlchemy create the tables if they don't exist using `create_all()`

Comment: Am I not doing this in db_session.py In a line 'SqlAlchemyBase.metadata.create_all(engine)' ?

Comment: Also, as I think, the table is created, but for some reason I can’t update it

Comment: The `create_all` method needs to be run after you have declared your models; if you want to check that the tables are created just open the SQLite database file and check the tables.

Comment: But I run it after I declare all models (in 'from data import __all_models') and when I open SQLite database file it says the table is created.

Comment: I'm sure  the table is created and the problem is that I can't update it because the program says "no such table" and I don't now why if I just created this table.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code your using? Because `f'sqlite:///{db_file.strip() check_same_thread=False'` should give a syntax error. Perhaps you're creating multiple database files?

Comment: I've made a mistake while copying code, it should be 'f'sqlite:///{db_file.strip()}?check_same_thread=False''.

Comment: I'm sure I'm creating just one database because I check whether the database is already created here: 'if __factory:
        return'